# ServiceStack request fails with error 401, but the Session is authenticated

Tags: servicestack

In GlobalRequestFilters I have something like this:

```
var session = new AuthUserSession()
{
    AuthProvider = "credentials",
    IsAuthenticated = true,
    Id = $"a unique string",
    ...
};
req.Items[Keywords.Session] = session;
```

I have class like this:

```
[Authenticate]
[Route($"/Test", "POST" )]
public class CreateTest : ICreateDb<Test>, IReturn<CreateTestResponse>
{
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

And a service:

```
public class TestService : ServiceStack.Service
{
   public object Post(CreateTest request)
   {
       // prints "True" (when we comment [Authenticate] in the DTO)
       Console.Write( Request.GetSession().IsAuthenticated ); 
   }
}
```

When I test this service in "/ui" I receive error 401.

If I comment the "[Authenticate]" attribute from the "CreateTest", it works as expected, and I can confirm that the session exists and "IsAuthenticated" is True.

Is my understanding that is enough to "assign" a Session to the current Request in order to Authenticate that request, but something is missing.

What can I do to troubleshoot this 401 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should the debug the [CredentialsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs) to find out why your session isn't valid, e.g. you may have missed populating `Email` or `UserAuthName` field it requires.

Comment: the fields are populated. I think the problem is related with the execution order. I can see that `AuthenticateAttribute` / `ExecuteAsync`  is executed before `GlobalRequestFilters`.

Therefore, I don't have the chance to store the Session object in `Request.Items[Keywords.Session]`.

Does it make sense?

The strange thing is that the behavior seems to differ depending if `[Authenticate]` is places at Service level or "Action" level.

Is there a guaranteed way to affect Request.Items[Keywords.Session] before the [Authenticate] attribute is evaluated?

Comment: Yeah Authentication is implemented using [Request Filter Attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) which are [executed before GlobalRequestFilters](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) with [-100 Priority](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/RequestFilterPriority.cs), you can run logic before with a Request Filter Attribute with a lower priority or a [PreRequestFilter](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) which are executed before Request Filter Attributes.

Comment: I confirm that using the PreRequestFilter solver the problem! Thank you